# Defnining a function with a parameter which is not a slot but a constant

Tags: functional-style, slot

One convenient way to define a function is

```
f[S,x_]:= 3
f[G,x_]:= 7
```

where the first parameter is not a slot but a constant. This way of constructing functions is convenient to have multiple definitions attached to a function symbol `f`.

However, in order to use `DistributeDefinitions`, functions must be defined using `Function`. How can I program the above two definitions using `Function`? I tried

```
f = Function[{name, x}, 3]/;name=S
```

but this does not work. An obvious workaround is to define a single `f` function with a `Switch` inside it, but it does not have the elegance of distinct functions with a constant parameter.

Alternatively, if you know how to distribute definitions of functions to multiple kernels, e.g., `DistributionDefinition[f]`, that would also solve this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit 01

I guess I should've checked the OP's code first, which indeed also seems to work for me.

```
h[S, x_] := x^2
h[G, x_] := x^3
DistributeDefinitions[h]

ParallelEvaluate[h[S, $KernelID]]
ParallelEvaluate[h[G, $KernelID]]
```

`{1, 4, 9, 16}`
`{1, 8, 27, 64}`

### Original Post

Does this work for you?

```
f["square"][x_] := x^2
f["cube"][x_] := x^3
DistributeDefinitions[f]

ParallelEvaluate[f["square"][$KernelID]]
ParallelEvaluate[f["cube"][$KernelID]]
```

Which gives (for my 4 parallel kernels):
`{1, 4, 9, 16}`
`{1, 8, 27, 64}`

In general, I often use this paradigm to emulate ['multiple-dispatch'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) of sorts. One way of doing this is using an operator-like syntax of the form `f[constant][arguments__]:=...`, which defines `SubValues`.

Comment: Thanks @george-varnavides. Trying multiple options, I found out that `g /: g[S, x_] := x^2; g /: g[G, x_] := x^3; DistributeDefinitions[g]` seems to work as well. However, I can't understand why... Any clue?

Comment: @DenisCousineau from the Documentation for `DistributeDefinitions`: "DistributeDefinitions in effect applies ParallelEvaluate to all assignments for values and attributes with the symbols Subscript[s, i], including not only ownvalues but also downvalues, upvalues, and other types of values". What I showed used `SubValues` for `f`, where as  your `TagSetDelayed` method defines `DownValues` for `g` which both seem to be supported by `DistributeDefinitions`. In-fact, your original code also seems to work - see Edit.